# How to datetime parse a non-standardized time format

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I would like to create `datetime` objects from a list of string timecodes like these. However, `parse` interprets incorrectly for my use case.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

timecodes = ['0:00', '0:01', '1:01', '10:01', '1:10:01']

dt = parser.parse(timecode)
print(dt)
```

The list above comes from YouTube's transcript timecodes. When copied from the site, they use a variable format to designate hours, minutes, and time, based on elapsed time:

```
0:00     # 0 minutes, 0 seconds
0:01     # 0 minutes, 1 seconds
1:01     # 1 minutes, 1 seconds
10:01    # 10 minutes, 1 seconds
1:10:01  # 1 hours, 10 minutes, 1 seconds
```

and `parse` results in (comments are my interpretations):

```
2022-10-24 00:00:00    #0 minutes, 0 seconds
2022-10-24 00:01:00    #1 minutes, 0 seconds
2022-10-24 01:01:00    #1 hours, 1 minutes, 0 seconds
2022-10-24 10:01:00    #10 hours, 1 minutes, 0 seconds
2022-10-24 01:10:01    #1 hours, 10 minutes, 1 seconds
```

i.e. if a string doesn't consist of a full timecode including hours, minutes, seconds, then `parse` appears to think that minutes are hours, and seconds are minutes.

How can I either dynamically parse the list to default interpretation to minutes & seconds instead of hours & minutes, or alternatively adjust the timecodes intelligently so that they conform to the `parse` format?

Comment: If no other option is available, you could just prepend `0:` to any time string that only has one `:`.

Comment: `dateutil` is parsing time *stamps*, not time intervals. The two are distinct concepts, but frequently conflated. `parse` is also consistent: `0:00` is really parsed as `0 hours, 0 minutes`; it just happens to be equivalent to `0 minutes, 0 seconds`. It assumes hours/minutes, with seconds as the optional third field, rather than minutes/seconds with hours as the optional third field.

Comment: If you are interested, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) has a dedicated format for durations (the term I should have used instead of "intervals", which is yet *another* separate concept :)): `PT1M`, e.g., would represent a period of time of 1 minute, independent of when the period *starts*. (Intervals allow you to specify start times, stop times, and durations in various combinations.)

Comment: All of which is to say, it's too bad YouTube doesn't use the more well-defined, but less familiar, standard notation instead of the ambiguous but intuitive notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky but should work:

```
import datetime
timecodes = ['0:00', '0:01', '1:01', '10:01', '1:10:01']
zeroes = ['0','0','0']
dt = []
for i in timecodes:
    sep = i.split(':')
    sep = zeroes[:3-len(sep)] + sep
    dt.append(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = sum([int(s) * 60**(2-sep.index(s)) for s in sep]))))
```

Output:

```
dt = ['0:00:00', '0:00:01', '0:01:01', '0:10:01', '1:10:01']
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is to map the duration components to integers in reverse order (seconds, minutes, hours), and convert to seconds by multiplication with the appropriate factors (1, 60, 3600) using `zip`. `sum` that up to get the total seconds, with you can convert to timedelta:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

timecodes = ['0:00', '0:01', '1:01', '10:01', '1:10:01']

for t in timecodes:
    print(
        timedelta(seconds=sum(a*b for a, b in zip(map(int, t.split(":")[::-1]), (1, 60, 3600))))
        )
    
0:00:00
0:00:01
0:01:01
0:10:01
1:10:01
```